# Why are generic input parameter properties not accessible?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I'm building a small repository pattern in Dotnet Web Api for accessing a db with a controller, a repository/unit of work and input params specific to each controller. However, when I pass my input type to the repository (which has a generic interface), I can't access the properties on that.

I've tried to create a base repository interface that has a generic type for an input parameter. Then in the concrete respository for each data type, I specify the concrete type that will be passed in. However, I can't seem to access any properties of that type in the repository method body.

I'm pretty new to generics, so I feel like I'm missing something but can't seem to figure it out.

Basic steps to reproduce:

1. Create input POCO

   ```
   public class MetDataInput {
       public bool Precipitation = true;
   }
   ```
2. Repository Interface has one method signature

   ```
   public interface IRepositoryBase {
       public Task<IReadOnlyList<dynamic>> GetAllAsync<T>(T inputParams);
   }
   ```
3. Concrete repositories define the type for T

   ```
   public class MetDataRepository : IRepositoryBase
   {
     //specify T here
     public async Task<IReadOnlyList<dynamic>> GetAllAsync<MetDataInput>(MetDataInput input) 
     {
         //Why can't I access the properties of input here.
         //compiler claims input does not contain definition for Precipitation
         Console.WriteLine(input.precipitation)

         return await ResultObjectNotImportantInThisExample(input)
     }
   }
   ```
4. Create a controller and call the repository

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll([FromBody] MetDataInput input) 
   {
       var data = await metDataRepository.GetAllAsync<MetDataInput>(input)
   }
   ```

I'm trying to avoid having to define non-generic methods in the repository interface as this would be a lot of repetition for other controllers and repositories which are the same, but with different input classes.

Comment: Are you sure the `MetaDataInput` has the same namespace as you one you want to target?

Comment: Actually, no. I just noticed that in the conrete repo, the method signature isn't using the concrete type, it's just treating the type definition as if I had written T. But, then i also can't cast to the concrete type in the body.

Comment: So then the error makes sense.

Comment: It does, but I'm still not understanding how to pass in the type from the controller and be able to access it's properties in the concrete repository. How do I tell the repository what T is going to be?

Comment: You can try match casting. `if (input is MetaData metaDataInput) {  Console.WriteLine(input.precipitation); }` It isn't really a good answer but it might work in your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

In the signature of `MetDataRepository.GetAllAsync<MetDataInput>(MetDataInput input)`, that is written between `<?>` is the generic parameter name. In you case `MetDataInput`. Then in the scope of the method, `MetDataInput` don't reference the type, but the generic parameter.

A solution is to use a generic interface like :

```cs
public interface IRepositoryBase<T>
{
    public Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetAllAsync(T inputParams);
}

public class MetDataRepository : IRepositoryBase<MetDataInput>
{
    public async Task<IReadOnlyList<MetDataInput>> GetAllAsync(MetDataInput input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input.Precipitation);
        return await ResultObjectNotImportantInThisExample(input)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow. In your example you have changed the output type of the method to Task<IReadOnlyList<MetDataInput>... but MetaDataInput is the input to the method, not the output. The output type is IReadOnlyList<SomeUnRelatedType>, in my case I'm using a dynamic type for the output.

Comment: It's a bonus to avoid `dynamic`, but you can keep.